# ConEmu Cannot Delete Selected Text

Tags: conemu

In ConEmu I try to select text with my cursor or mouse but attempting to delete does not delete my command. This is necessary because I don't want to waste my time deleting one letter at a time.

How do I accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no, because when you highlight something, it's not as though the console actually knows that, it's just the ConEmu interface allowing some copy & paste ease of use.

This link is helpful:
https://web.archive.org/web/20131201092601/http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/issues/detail?id=1332